# CNN in Graphlab.create() on MNIST data

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, graphlab

I am trying the identification of digits from MNIS datasets. I am using graphlab.create. The dataset is MNIST data.

First I read the dataset:

```
    %pylab inline
    import graphlab as gl
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    from scipy.misc import imread
    import graphlab.aggregate as agg

    temp=[]
    for img_name in train.filename:
         image_path= os.path.join(data_dir, 'Train', 'Images', 'train', img_name)
         img=imread(image_path)
         img=img.astype('float32')
         temp.append(img)

     tr_x=np.stack(temp)

     temp=[]
     for img_name in test.filename:
         image_path=os.path.join(data_dir,'Train', 'Images','test',img_name)
         img=imread(image_path)
         img=img.astype('float32')
         temp.append(img)

     te_x=np.stack(temp)
```

tr_x is of shape (49000L, 28L, 28L, 4L), where an image is (28,28,4) and there are 49000 images.

```
         sa3=gl.SArray(train_y)
         tr_y=gl.SFrame([sa3])
         tr_y.rename({'X1':'label'})
```

Then I prepared a CNN :

```
       #Building a custom network
       #A network’s architecure is defined by a list of layer objects.
        conv_net = gl.deeplearning.ConvolutionNet(num_convolution_layers=2,
                                          kernel_size=3,
                                          num_channels=10,
                                          num_output_units=10)
       conv_net.layers
```

Then I create the model object:

```
       m3=gl.neuralnet_classifier.create(tr_x, target=tr_y['label'],   network=conv_net, metric=['accuracy'], max_iterations=3)
```

After this I am getting error message regarding input_shape. It will be helpful if I get some guidance regarding running CNN in graphlab.
I have read the documentation of Graphlab.create but couldn't resolve the error.